# Adding a href to an i class

Tags: html

Hi guys this might be a silly question but i am trying to make my i class have a link to anthoer page but for some reason its not working

```
          <ul class="get_in">
             <li>
                <i class="fa fa-facebook"  <a href="www.google.com"></a> </i>
                <i class="fa fa-instagram"></i>
                 <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i>
             </li>
          </ul>
```

Again it might be silly but any help would be great , thanks x

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<a href="www.google.com"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do either of this two

```
<a href="...url..."><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
```

or

```
<i class="fa fa-facebook"><a href="...url..."></a> </i>
```

But i will prefer to use the first one.

Answer (score 0):

You have to finish your *italic* start tag with a `>` **before** you write your *anchor* start tag.

```
<i class="fa fa-facebook"><a href="www.google.com"></a> </i>
```